# Thread 10: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I am trying to make a service call to get user details however i get this error :

**Thread 10: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

From this code :

```
    let urlString = "http://myURL.com/getInfo/getAccountTransactions/{accountPublicKey}"
    print(urlString)
    let requestUrl = URL(string:urlString)
    let requestURL = URLRequest(url:requestUrl!)
```

When i wrap the code in a guard let the code doesn't get executed because it finds nil, i am not sure why because the URL string can never be nill since its initialized with a default value on the same code.

This the code in a guard let :

```
    let urlString = "http://myURL.com/getInfo/getAccountTransactions/{accountPublicKey}"
    guard let requestUrl = URL(string:urlString) else { return }
    let requestURL = URLRequest(url:requestUrl)
```

This the entire service call code :

```
class TransactionServiceCall : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate{

let viewResponse = ThrowResponse()

func fetchTransactions(requestObject: Transaction, completion: @escaping (Dictionary<String,Any>?) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "http://myURL.com/getInfo/getAccountTransactions/{accountPublicKey}"

    guard let requestUrl = URL(string:urlString) else { return }
    let requestURL = URLRequest(url:requestUrl)

    let searchParams = Transaction.init(publicKey: requestObject.publicKey)
    var request = requestURL
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try?  searchParams.jsonData()
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        do {
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if 200 ... 299 ~= statusCode {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                    self.viewResponse.dismissLoader()
                    print(json)
                    completion(json)
                }
            }else{
                self.viewResponse.dismissLoader()
                self.viewResponse.showFailureAlert(title: "Failure", message: "")
                completion(nil)
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.viewResponse.dismissLoader()
                self.viewResponse.showFailureAlert(title: "Failure", message: "")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()

  }

}
```

It is important to note that the url has curly brackets in it e.g

**http://myURL.com/getInfo/getAccountTransactions/{accountPublicKey}**

Comment: If the URL cannot be created then `urlString` has the wrong format.

Comment: What happens if you try `URLComponents(string: urlString)?.url` instead of `URL(string:)`? `URLComponents` uses a newer RFC to create URLs, and without knowing what your URL is (`"http://myURL.com/getInfo"` works on my machine), it's not inconceivable that that could alter the behavior.

Comment: URLComponents doesnt work also, another thing to note is that the url has curly brackets like this : http://myURL.com/getInfo/getAccountTransactions/{accountPublicKey}

Comment: in postman the url works fine and the curly brackets are part of the url

Comment: Hey this code working well

Comment: The same code works well with another request however the difference is that in the other request the url doesnt have curly brackets in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in the url `string` using `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` and an appropriate `CharacterSet` so that a valid `URL` object may be created from it.
In your case, the `CharacterSet` should be `.urlQueryAllowed`

Like so:

```
//The unescaped string
let unescaped = "http://myURL.com/getInfo/getAccountTransactions/{accountPublicKey}"

//The escaped string
let escaped = unescaped.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

//...
```